# Ubuntu 14.04 Centrify Not able to login through GDM

Tags: login, active-directory

We have an Active Directory Server running in my company. I need to add a Ubuntu desktop system to active directory domain. I followed [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DirectControl) guide to add ubuntu to windows domain. I was successfully able to join the domain. But when I rebooted and tried to login using my AD credentials I was not able to login. Here's the output of my adinfo:

```
Local host name:   ubuntutest12
Joined to domain:  mydomain.com
Joined as:         ubuntutest12.mydomain.com
Pre-win2K name:    ubuntutest12
Current DC:        adswsus2008.mydomain.com
Preferred site:    Default-First-Site-Name
Zone:              Auto Zone
CentrifyDC mode:   connected
Licensed Features: Disabled
```

where `mydomain` is a replacement for my actual domain name. I tried logging in using following usernames:

```
mydomain\sidyadav
mydomain\\sidyadav
mydomain.com\sidyadav
mydomain.com\\sidyadav
sidyadav
```

None of the methods worked. I don't understand where I'm failing. Any directions will be helpful.

NOTE: The Graphical login is not working. I'm able to ssh using my AD credentials.

Comment: I was able to login after enabling log, which is really odd. But that's how it worked. FYI, in case any one wants to try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm editing my reply with a more detailed and accurate answer.  Please refer to the link below for the answer to your inquiry, I hope it is helpful:

http://community.centrify.com/t5/DirectControl-Express-for-UNIX/Ubuntu-14-04-Centrify-Not-able-to-login-through-GDM/m-p/20494#M4244

I'll summarize the answer here as well just in case:

"Your GDM application is most likely not configured for PAM.  If you try to log in with your AD name (short name will be fine, or even UPN) via SSH, you'll be able to log in.

Another way for you to verify who can log in is this: 
In the command line
Perform an adquery user command.  This will show you all the users from AD who can log in to the box.
As root or with sudo, type this:

sudo su -

You should see something like "Created Home Directory" if you type the ID command, you'll see that you're the user, but this is a good test, because uses su and bypasses the GDM.

Since the adjustments from Ubuntu change from version to version, just find out how to PAM-enable the GDM and you'll be golden."

In the future please use the Centrify community page (http://community.centrify.com) for the fastest and most direct help with the Centrify Express component.

Best of luck with your deployment efforts.  If you need further assistance please post further replies in the forum link above and we will gladly provide continued assistance.

Hubert